# Apache activeMQ, creating queue dynamically from client side

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, stomp

Goal is, create an HTML page which can send and receive updates from server.

I created HTML page and made connection with Apache ActiveMQ via STOMP over websocket and wrote Java code at server side which will send updates to those queue. This works fine, but ideally HTML page will be used by many users, so I want each to have their separate queue( dynamically generated) and listen and send on their respective queue only. HTML client would be able to register queue but thing which I don't know is how my server side code will get notified, do we have any callback func for this? Tried with DestinationSource class which does tell how many queue's exist but not clear how to get access to that queue

Am I going on wrong path for solving this? Any help/link/info on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into ActiveMQ Advisory Message's which can fire events for various things such as Destination creation and destruction, no consumer, message expiration etc.

The ActiveMQ site has [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) on this.